# Работа .outerWidth(true) в Chrome

Tags: jquery, select2

Некорректно работает `.outerWidth(true)` и другие функции получения ширины объекта в Chrome. Один и тот же блок, в Firefox показывает 370px, а в Chrome 388px. Вывожу ширину в `alert()`. Но фактическая ширина блока, если измерить пиксельной линейкой одинаковая в обоих браузерах. Суть скрипта - получать ширину блока обёртки и задавать такую же ширину у `select`. В чём тут подвох?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var select_body_item_value = $('#select_body_item option:selected').text(); //получаем содержимое выбранного элемента селекта

        $('#select_placeholder_item').text(select_body_item_value); //записываем содержимое выбранного пункта селекта в плейсхолдер

        var select_wrap_item_width = $('#select_wrap_item').outerWidth(true); //получаем ширину обёртки селекта

        $('#select_body_item').width(select_wrap_item_width); //устанавливаем ширину селекта равной ширине обёртки селекта

        $('#select_body_item').change(function(){
            var select_body_item_value = $('#select_body_item option:selected').text(); //получаем содержимое выбранного элемента селекта

            $('#select_placeholder_item').text(select_body_item_value); //записываем содержимое выбранного пункта селекта в плейсхолдер

            var select_wrap_item_width = $('#select_wrap_item').width(); //получаем ширину обёртки селекта

            $('#select_body_item').width(select_wrap_item_width); //устанавливаем ширину селекта равной ширине обёртки селекта
        });
        alert(select_wrap_item_width);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выставить принудительно Css box-sizing: border-box и  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Для Firefox */. Тогда у вас будет одинаковый алгоритм расчета ширины и высоты элемента во всех браузерах.

Comment: Dmitry, спасибо. box-sizing: border-box стоял. Попробую выставить ещё и -moz-box-sizing: border-box